# Calling C# getter from UpdatePanel / javascript - never get updated data

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have this property in my code-behind.

```
public string LocationOptions
{
    get { return Session["LocationOptions"].ToString(); }
    set { Session["LocationOptions"] = value; }
}
```

On the front-end, I have this javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad(sender, args) {           
        InitLocationsAutoComplete();
    }
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upScript" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>
         <script type="text/javascript">
            function InitLocationsAutoComplete() {
                var locationsJson = '<%= LocationOptions %>';
                alert(locationsJson);
            }
        </script>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I'm setting a breakpoint on my getter and setter in the C# code.

I'm using MVP and the setter gets called from a presenter.

On first page load, things work as expected.  The breakpoint on the setter gets hit first.  Then the breakpoint on the getter.  Finally, I get a javascript alert with the value I expect to see.

I'm running into problems on partial postbacks that are triggered by other update panels.  On those, my setter breakpoint hits with a new value.  My getter breakpoint gets hit next, and if I quick watch `Session["LocationOptions"]` I see the new value there.  But when I get the javascript alert, it still alerts the initial value from the first page load.

If it still calls the property in C#, then I don't see why the updated value doesn't come through to the javascript.  Why am I stuck with the initial value from first page load?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, javascript in the partially updated content is not re-executed/re-evaluated. My understanding is that the partial update will essentially edit the DOM to update a part of the page, but this does not allow one to dynamically upate javascript on the page. You can use `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` on the server-side to register your updated javascript during the partial postback.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue in the past.

The issue is due to the fact that the dom is only partially updated, i've personally corrected this by registering the script in the ScriptManager.

An example of this is here:  [ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method (Control, Type, String, String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb350750.aspx)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<script runat="server">
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string script = @"
    function ToggleItem(id)
      {
        var elem = $get('div'+id);
        if (elem) 
        {
          if (elem.style.display != 'block') 
          {
            elem.style.display = 'block';
            elem.style.visibility = 'visible';
          } 
          else
          {
            elem.style.display = 'none';
            elem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          }
        }
      }
    ";

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        this,
        typeof(Page),
        "ToggleScript",
        script,
        true);
}

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>ScriptManager RegisterClientScriptInclude</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" 
                             EnablePartialRendering="true"
                             runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" 
                           UpdateMode="Conditional"
                           runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1"
                                   DataFile="~/App_Data/Contacts.xml"
                                   XPath="Contacts/Contact"
                                   runat="server"/>
                <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"
                    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#E7E7FF" BorderStyle="None"
                    BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Horizontal"
                    runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <div style="font-size:larger; font-weight:bold; cursor:pointer;" 
                             onclick='ToggleItem(<%# Eval("ID") %>);'>
                            <span><%# Eval("Name") %></span>
                        </div>
                        <div id='div<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
                             style="display: block; visibility: visible;">
                            <span><%# Eval("Company") %></span>
                            <br />
                            <a href='<%# Eval("URL") %>' 
                               target="_blank" 
                               title='<%# Eval("Name", "Link to the {0} Web site") %>'>
                               <%# Eval("URL") %></a>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                            <hr />
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                    <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                    <ItemStyle BackColor="#E7E7FF" ForeColor="#4A3C8C" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#F7F7F7" />
                </asp:DataList>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

i hope this helps.